# How to install OpenCV version 2 using anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

Noob question here (Just starting out on anaconda)
I want to install OpenCV version 2 but everywhere on the net there are instructions for installing version 3 only.

Comment: What did you tried? What were the errors? What resources did you use (tutos, docs)? What is your Operating System and version?

Answer (score 0):

Just like "pip install" anaconda uses "conda install" You can try this syntax:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Hope this will help. You can find detailed documentation here:
[OpenCV | Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv)

Comment: Might be worth to also mention a more general approach here: Go to [the anaconda page](https://anaconda.org/), at the top: type in the package you are looking for and check in which channel the package is available, then specify the channel name with `-c <channel name>`